# Call to a member function named() on null in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have this route

```
Route::get('/books/science', 'BookController@science')->name('scientific');
```

When I wanted to check this condition (according to document: [Inspecting The Current Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes))

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->route()->named('scientific')) {
        //
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I got this error. Also when I add "Route"

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

and dump these codes

```
dd(Route::currentRouteName());
dd(\Request::route());
```

I get null

Comment: Where is the `handle` method and how is it being called? The example in the docs is specific to Middleware.

Comment: yes. it is in Middleware and middleware is registered in protected $middleware of kernel.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->route()` will return null in **Global Middlewares**.

Add your middleware in a different group as

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
         ...
         YOUR_MIDDLEWARE::class,
    ]
]
```

or add it in `$routeMiddleware`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'your_middleware' => YOUR_MIDDLEWARE::class,
];
```

and apply it to your route,

```
Route::middleware('your_middleware')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/books/science', 'BookController@science')->name('scientific');
});
```